# CERTBOT No valid IP addresses found for "SUBDOMAIN" in NGINX server

Tags: nginx, ssl, certbot

[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCbib.png)

I want to generate a **CERTBOT** SSL Certificate on my self-hosted Ubuntu server for the **NGINX** server. But I get an error for

```
Type:   DNS
Detail: No valid IP addresses found for domain
```

Comment: You need to create a DNS record for your subdomain.